# Get previous weekday from sql date string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a date string in sql format (eg `2017-08-05`) and will like to convert it to get the previous weekday.

I know that there is the `strtotime` method where I can get the previous weekday from a specific date, such as:

```
date("Y m d",strtotime("-2 Weekday", strtotime("2017-08-05")));
```

Is there a better (prettier) way to do this? Or is this the PHP way?

Comment: Weekday as in Monday to Friday or any day?

Comment: Hi @Andreas, the date could be any day, but the output should be the previous weekday (mon-fri)

Comment: The current solution works, I just thought it was strange that the same method occurs twice in the same line and there would be a better solution

Comment: `date("Y m d", strtotime("2017-08-05 -2 Weekday"))`

Comment: Hi @JoeBlack, thank you for the response. Will you like to post it as an answer below so that I can accept it?

Comment: @PohZiHow Ok, posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same can be achieved with just one call to `strtotime`:

```
date("Y m d", strtotime("2017-08-05 -2 Weekday"))
```

Comment: This is nice and simple, but it gives you a `string`. If you prefer manipulating objects, you should use `DateTime`, `DateTimeImmutable`, and `DateInterval` to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1):

By using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
Carbon::parse('2017-08-05')->previousWeekday()
```

Or if you want sameway

```
Carbon::parse('2017-08-05')->subWeekday(2)->toDateString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// create a new instance of DateTimeImmutable
$date = new \DateTimeImmutable('2017-08-05');

// create a one-day interval
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');

// subtract the interval, and keep doing that while the day before is not a weekday
do {
    $date = $date->sub($interval);
} while (5 < $date->format('N'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/aT6Zj

Answer (score 0):

you can create a carbon

```
carbon::parse('2012-08-05')->previousWeekday();
```

No better way then this...